# How can I test a potential relay on my AC

Tags: hvac, relay, capacitor

My starter capacitor failed so I installed another one and it failed also.I was told if the relay failed it could blow the capacitor.
I tested the relay and it is normally closed, how can I test it to see if it is opening when it should . I opened the relay and the contacts have not welded together.